# Problem in snowflake when using expression on values clause for an INSERT statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I am having this problem with Snowflake.
I have some insert statement like these inside an Snowflake SP:

```sql
DROP TABLE TABLE1;

CREATE table TABLE1 (COLUMN1 VARCHAR(10));

insert into table1 values('TEST' || TRIM(0));
```

When I execute those statements I get an error like this:
**`SQL compilation error: Invalid expression ['TEST' || '0'] in VALUES clause`**

Is there a documented limitation for the VALUES clause in snowflake. Any kind of work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a **workaround** for the limitation that @mike-walton described.
You can chance:

```sql
insert into table1 values('TEST' || TRIM(0));
```

to

```sql
insert into table1 select 'TEST' || TRIM(0);
```

And it will work

Comment: I was going to bring that up, but since you were focused on VALUES, I assumed there were more than 1 value.  Using a SELECT for multiple values will cause you to need a whole lot of `UNION ALL` statements.  Is there a reason you need a TRIM for a numeric value?

Comment: Well I did not wrote that code was just taking from another database to Snowflake. In that case they had something like TRIM('WEEK' || TRIM(CODE)) and code was a varchar. I think that the extra TRIM was not needed but also 'WEEK' || TRIM(CODE) was failing

Comment: @MikeWalton what would you recommend if we do have multiple values?

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values.html

> Each expression must be a constant, or an expression that can be
> evaluated as a constant during compilation of the SQL statement.
>
> Most simple arithmetic expressions and string functions can be
> evaluated at compile time, but most other expressions cannot.

In looking at your example, you are using a `TRIM` on a numeric expression, which isn't necessary.  If you remove the `TRIM()`, then your example works fine.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that restriction. i found however a workaround that I am posting as asnwer